# Anybody know any WMS clients for Android?

Tags: wms, open-source-gis, android

I am interested in finding a project (with source) for a WMS client for Android.

Answer (score 4):

gvSIG mini

http://confluence.prodevelop.es/display/GVMN/Home

Comment: That's the only one I know about with source.

Comment: I have tried it, although I can get it running, it does not want to read my WMS.  I need to play with it more.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) inside of a WebView, though it probably won't perform as well as amac's answer.

Comment: http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/ is another option down the same path as OpenLayers, possibly more suited to mobile.

Answer (score 2):

QGIS Mobile for Android supports WMS. It's a port of QGIS Desktop created during this years Google Summer of Code. Currently, it's only recommended for use on Android tablets since there is no dedicated mobile GUI yet.

For more info check the author's website: http://www.bernawebdesign.ch/byteblog/2011/08/24/gsoc-2011-final-report/

Answer (score 1):

My multitouch mapping client [kivyMaps](http://relet.github.com/kivyMaps/) runs on Android. It supports WMS, WMS-C and I am working on simple WFS support. It's aimed mainly at showcasing services with a clean interface, so it does not have a fully fledged UI or android settings screen, but you might just as well see this as a mapping framework and develop your own application around it.

It builds on top of [kivy](http://kivy.org), so you can run the same code on Android, Windows, Linux and MacOSX (iOS is experimental).

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.azavea.com/blogs/labs/2013/01/wms-on-android/) might help for basic needs but i cannot assure for further needs such as on click info window